# Why is this dynamic array implementation slower than std::vector<T>?

Tags: c++, malloc

Bellow is a simple template array implementation using malloc and realloc

Stepping through with a debugger, there were less code steps than vector. 
However, when timing using std::chrono, std::vector is still faster.

Why is this?

(Compiling using gnu cc v9)

```
#include <../array.hpp>
#include <../console.hpp>

#include <vector>

int main() {
    console::time("array");
    array<int> a { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    console::timeEnd("array");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        console::log(std::to_string(a[i]));
    }

    array<int> b { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 };
    if (a != b) {
        console::log("a != b");
    }

    array<int> c { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    if (a == c) {
        console::log("a == c");
    }

    console::time("std::vector");
    vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    console::timeEnd("std::vector");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        console::log(std::to_string(v[i]));
    }

    return 0;
};
```

```
array: 27µs - timer ended
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
a != b
a == c
std::vector: 2655ns - timer ended
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Full implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/universefullofthings/ac933d64158217478a02df7bdcc8f319?.

Comment: Your test is microscopic considering the speed of modern computers. Try it with something like a million elements to get more meaningful results.

Comment: Also ensure you are using optimised code and post a [mre] within the question itself not as external links

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour if used for non POD types

Comment: What is class `array`?   It is something different from `std::array`  (the templated type in standard header `<array>`).    Nobody has a hope of explaining why it performs differently than `std::vector` unless they have some inkling about how it works.

Comment: Class `array` in the example is the implementation provided in the gist.

Comment: I will try with a larger number of elements, however it's clear the std:: implementations use some other form of memory mapping than malloc, which is clear has a larger performance impact.